# get set properties in php

Tags: php, get, set

I'm from the C# environment and I'm starting to learn PHP in school.
I'm used to set my properties in C# like this.

```
public int ID { get; set; }
```

What's the equivalent to this in php?

Thanks.

Answer (score 34):

There is none, although there are [some proposals for implementing](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/propertygetsetsyntax) that in future versions.
For now you unfortunately need to declare all getters and setters by hand.

```
private $ID;

public function setID($ID) {
  $this->ID = $ID;
}

public function getID() {
  return $this->ID;
}
```

for some magic (PHP likes magic), you can look up `__set` and `__get` [magic methods.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

Example

```
class MyClass {

  private $ID;

  private function setID($ID) {
    $this->ID = $ID;
  }

  private function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
  }


  public function __set($name,$value) {
    switch($name) { //this is kind of silly example, bt shows the idea
      case 'ID': 
        return $this->setID($value);
    }
  }

  public function __get($name) {
    switch($name) {
      case 'ID': 
        return $this->getID();
    }
  }

}


$object = new MyClass();
$object->ID = 'foo'; //setID('foo') will be called
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks for your answers everyone. It helped me to create something like this:

In my parent class:

```
public function __get($name){

    if (ObjectHelper::existsMethod($this,$name)){
        return $this->$name();
    }

    return null;
}

public function __set($name, $value){

    if (ObjectHelper::existsMethod($this,$name))
        $this->$name($value);
}
```

ObjectHelper::existsMethod is a method which just check if given protected method exists.

```
private $_propertyName = null;

protected function PropertyName($value = ""){

    if (empty($value)) // getter
    {
        if ($this-> _propertyName != null)
            return $this->_propertyName;
    }
    else // setter
    {
        $this-> _propertyName = $value;
    }

    return null;
}
```

So I can use something like this in any class:

```
$class = new Class();
$class->PropertyName = "test";
echo $class->PropertyName;
```

I was inspired by C# :)

What do you think about this, guys?

Here is my ObjectHelper if someone would like to use it:

```
namespace Helpers;

use ReflectionMethod;

class ObjectHelper {

public static function existsMethod($obj, $methodName){

    $methods = self::getMethods($obj);

    $neededObject = array_filter(
        $methods,
        function ($e) use($methodName) {
            return $e->Name == $methodName;
         }
    );

    if (is_array($neededObject))
        return true;

    return false;
}

public static function getMethods($obj){

    $var = new \ReflectionClass($obj);

    return $var->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PROTECTED);
}
}
```

Comment: I would like to use something like this to reduce the tedious boilerplate of PHP get/set usage. Can I suggest some improvements to your approach? 1) add a naming-convention requirement of "getPropertyName" and "setPropertyName" prefixes to the methods, to avoid callers being able to call ALL methods as properties, which will lead to confusion (or add a const list of properties).

Comment: 2) It would be much easier to use a Trait rather than a parent class (probably not available when you wrote this).

Comment: 3) continue to expand the helper to do the actual get/set boilerplate via a property naming-convention and a dynamic $propertyName. This would be the most valuable part to me. I've never bothered with PHP's get/set due to the amount of extra repeat code for each property.

Comment: 4) tighten up the empty check for "get" case. As noted by others, you will want to set the property to emptyish values, certainly 0 and "" and []. Null seems the best, although it still precludes actually setting the property to null. I can't see an easy way around that ATM, other than another method, or not doing the getset single function.

Comment: And once all that is in place, I guess a performance benchmark might not go amiss! Considering setting a property is such a low-level activity, performance could be critical for some objects or their usages. Perhaps hard-coded (or generated) boilerplate is much more efficient after all.

Answer (score 6):

[Mchi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9320371/662581) is right, but there is another way of doing it by using single function

```
    private $ID;

public function ID( $value = "" )

{

    if( empty( $value ) )

        return $this->ID;

    else

        $this->ID = $value;

}
```

But yeah this approach is pretty much inline with what you do in c#. but this is only an alternative

Or try using php's __set and __get in your class more info here

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

Comment: Although an interesting approach, I see some disadvantages: First of all, the name of the function does not imply what it does (no verb in it), secondly what if I specifically wanted to set an empty value to ID?  `$class->ID(4); $class->ID(''); echo $class->ID();` would print 4 ...

Comment: @cassy. thats why i said its an alternative. in c# you dont have setX or getX as such even though you can have them, so I thought I better show something which can be in line with c# a bit :) the example you listed to highlight a disadvantage of above approach. I am with you on it but there are heaps of things that you can do to make it the way you want it. So my idea was only to show an approach not a solution.

Comment: Excuse the necro. But this can be done more effectively now with PHP's variadic ... operator. `function foo(...$args) { if (empty($args)) { return $this->foo; } else { $this->foo = $args[0]; } }`

Answer (score 5):

Another exampled using Variable function name

```
class MyClass {

  private $ID;
  protected $ID2;

  private function setID($ID) {
    $this->ID = $ID;
  }
  private function getID() {
    return $this->ID;
  }
  private function setID2($ID2) {
    $this->ID2 = $ID2;
  }

  private function getID2() {
    return $this->ID2;
  }
  public function __set($name,$value) {
    $functionname='set'.$name;
    return $this->$functionname($value);
  }
  public function __get($name) {
    $functionname='get'.$name;
    return $this->$functionname();
  }

}


$object = new MyClass();
$object->ID = 'foo'; //setID('foo') will be called
$object->ID2 = 'bar'; //setID2('bar') will be called
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private $ID;

public function getsetID($value = NULL)
{
    if ($value === NULL) {
        return $this->ID;
    } else {
        $this->ID = $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: How to set ID as null?

Comment: @MaximColesnic, `if (func_num_args() === 0)` can be used for that.

Answer (score 1):

I know I am a bit late to the party on this question, but I had the same question/thought myself.  As a C# developer who does PHP, when the job requires, I want to have a simple way to create properties just I would be able to in C#.

I whipped up a first draft this afternoon which allows you to create the backing fields and specify their accessors or have pure accessors with no backing field.  I will update my answer as the code evolves and provide a link when I get it to the state where it can be imported as a composer package.

For simplicity, I created the functionality as a PHP trait so you can drop it in to any class you want instead of having to extend a base class.  Eventually I hope to extend this functionality to discern between external public calls to the properties and protected/private calls.

Here is the code for the trait itself:

```
trait PropertyAccessorTrait
{
    private static $__propertyAccessors = [];

    /* @property string $__propertyPrefix */

    public function __get($name)
    {
        $this->__populatePropertyAcessors($name);

        return $this->__performGet($name);
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->__populatePropertyAcessors($name);

        $this->__performSet($name, $value);
    }

    public function __isset($name)
    {
        // TODO: Implement __isset() method.
    }

    public function __unset($name)
    {
        // TODO: Implement __unset() method.
    }

    protected function __getBackingFieldName($name)
    {
        if (property_exists(self::class, '__propertyPrefix')) {
            $prefix = $this->__propertyPrefix;
        } else {
            $prefix = '';
        }

        return $prefix . $name;
    }

    protected function __canget($name)
    {
        $accessors = $this->__getPropertyAccessors($name);

        return $accessors !== null && isset($accessors['get']);
    }

    protected function __canset($name)
    {
        $accessors = $this->__getPropertyAccessors($name);

        return $accessors !== null && isset($accessors['set']);
    }

    protected function __performGet($name)
    {
        if (!$this->__canget($name)) {
            throw new \Exception('Getter not allowed for property: ' . $name);
        }

        $accessors = $this->__getPropertyAccessors($name)['get'];

        /* @var \ReflectionMethod $method */
        $method = $accessors['method'];

        if (!empty($method)) {
            return $method->invoke($this);
        }

        return $this->{$this->__getBackingFieldName($name)};
    }

    protected function __performSet($name, $value)
    {
        if (!$this->__canset($name)) {
            throw new \Exception('Setter not allowed for property: ' . $name);
        }

        $accessors = $this->__getPropertyAccessors($name)['set'];

        /* @var \ReflectionMethod $method */
        $method = $accessors['method'];

        if (!empty($method)) {
            return $method->invoke($this, $value);
        }

        $this->{$this->__getBackingFieldName($name)} = $value;
    }

    protected function __getPropertyAccessors($name)
    {
        return isset(self::$__propertyAccessors[$name])
            ? self::$__propertyAccessors[$name]
            : null
            ;
    }

    protected function __getAccessorsFromDocBlock($docblock)
    {
        $accessors = [];

        if (!empty(trim($docblock))) {
            $doclines = null;

            if (!empty($docblock)) {
                $doclines = explode("\n", $docblock);
            }

            if (!empty($doclines)) {
                foreach ($doclines as $line) {
                    if (preg_match('/@(get|set)\\s+(public|private|protected)/', $line, $matches)) {
                        $accessors[$matches[1]]['visibility'] = $matches[2];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return $accessors;
    }

    protected function __populatePropertyAcessors($name)
    {
        if ($this->__getPropertyAccessors($name) !== null) return;

        try {
            $property = new \ReflectionProperty(self::class, $this->__getBackingFieldName($name));
        } catch (\ReflectionException $ex) {
            $property = null;
        }

        $accessors = [];

        if ($property != null) {
            $accessors = $this->__getAccessorsFromDocBlock($property->getDocComment());
        }

        try {
            $methodName = 'get' . ucfirst($name);
            $method = new \ReflectionMethod(self::class, $methodName);
            $method->setAccessible(true);
            $accessors = array_merge($accessors, $this->__getAccessorsFromDocBlock($method->getDocComment()));
        } catch (\ReflectionException $ex) {
            $method = null;
        }


        if ($method !== null || isset($accessors['get'])) {
            $accessors['get']['method'] = $method;
        }

        try {
            $methodName = 'set' . ucfirst($name);
            $method = new \ReflectionMethod(self::class, $methodName);
            $method->setAccessible(true);
            $accessors = array_merge($accessors, $this->__getAccessorsFromDocBlock($method->getDocComment()));
        } catch (\ReflectionException $ex) {
            $method = null;
        }

        if ($method !== null || isset($accessors['set'])) {
            $accessors['set']['method'] = $method;
        }

        self::$__propertyAccessors[$name] = $accessors;
    }
}
```

Here is a quick unit test I created using the Codeception format:

```
<?php

class PropertyAssesorTraitTestClass
{
    use PropertyAccessorTrait;

    private $__propertyPrefix = '_';

    /**
     * @get public
     * @set public
     */
    private $_integer = 1;

    /**
     * @get public
     */
    private $_getonly = 100;

    /**
     * @set public
     */
    private $_setonly;

    private $_customDoubler;

    private function getCustomDoubler()
    {
        return $this->_customDoubler * 2;
    }

    private function setCustomDoubler($value)
    {
        $this->_customDoubler = $value * 2;
    }

    public $publicField = 1234;

    /**
     * @return int
     * @get public
     */
    private function getPureAccessor()
    {
        return $this->publicField;
    }

    /**
     * @param $value
     * @set public
     */
    private function setPureAccessor($value)
    {
        $this->publicField = $value;
    }

    private $_purePrivate = 256;
}

$I = new UnitTester($scenario);
$I->wantTo('Ensure properties are accessed correctly');

$instance = new PropertyAssesorTraitTestClass();
$I->assertSame(1, $instance->integer);

$instance->integer = 2;
$I->assertSame(2, $instance->integer);

$instance->integer = $instance->integer + 1;
$I->assertSame(3, $instance->integer);

$instance->integer++;
$I->assertSame(4, $instance->integer);

$I->assertSame(100, $instance->getonly);
$I->expectException('Exception', function () use ($instance) { $instance->getonly = 50; });

$instance->setonly = 50;
$I->expectException('Exception', function () use ($instance) { $a = $instance->setonly; });

$instance->customDoubler = 100;
$I->assertSame(400, $instance->customDoubler);

$I->assertSame(1234, $instance->publicField);
$instance->pureAccessor = 1000;
$I->assertSame(1000, $instance->publicField);
$instance->publicField = 1234;
$I->assertSame(1234, $instance->publicField);
$I->assertSame(1234, $instance->pureAccessor);

$I->expectException('Exception', function () use ($instance) { return $instance->purePrivate; });
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
class MyClass
{
    private $name = null;

    public function __construct($name = null)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            $this->name = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        if (property_exists($this, $name)) {
            return $this->$name;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to use this pattern:

```php
class foo 
{
    //just add p as prefix to be different than method name.
    protected $pData;
    
    public funtion __construct() {} 
    public funtion __destruct() {}
    public funtion __clone() {}

    public function Data($value == "") 
    {
        if ($value != "") {
            $this->pData = $value;
        }
        return $this->pData;
    }
}
$myVar = new foo();
//for SET
$myVar->Data("A Value");
//for GET
$item = $myVar->Data();
```

Answer (score -5):

this is PHP ; you don't need get set

```
class MyClass {
  public $ID;
}

$object = new MyClass();
$object->ID = 'foo';
echo $object->ID;
```

will work